# How to deploy a Django site that uses numpy

Tags: python, django, server

I made a virtual environment on my local computer and installed numpy to be used in my web app. I found many tutorials on how to deploy django apps on a server, but I am not sure if those tutorial would work if my app depends on numpy. My app also uses static files some of which are csv files that are being parsed using python's csv library.

I am not sure where to look or what to look for that would help me get started with this process. Any ideas or guides that would help?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? For example setting up numpy in your server environment to see if it works?

Comment: not yet. I have no experience on how to do that, so I thought I should ask first before doing anything that might cause some problems down the road

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install numpy into your server environment and load static files there. You can do this by remote control via ssh for example. Also try to examine [docker](https://www.docker.com) for project environment creation. And start with deploying projects on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) - one of the best platforms for this task.